# Prove whether a well-formed formula in 0-order logic is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

and here is the question:

> Assume that $\tau$ is am element of $\mathcal{W}_p$, the set of well-formed formulas in $0$-order logic, such that there exists an infinite subset $X \subseteq \mathcal{L}_p^s$, the set of sentence symbols in $0$-order logic, with the property that
> $$(A \rightarrow \tau) \in \mathcal{T}_p, \text{ for all }A\in X$$
> Is it true that $\tau \in \mathcal{T}_p$? i.e., is $\tau$ a tautology?

Here is my **first** attempt:

Suppose for the contradiction that $\tau \notin \mathcal{T}_p$, then there exists some truth assignment $v$, whose domain contains the sentence symbols of $A$ and $\tau$, such that $v(\tau)=F$.

But, given that $(A \rightarrow \tau) \in \mathcal{T}_p$, and $v$ values the sentence symbols of $A,\tau$, hence $v(A\rightarrow \tau) = T$.

Combine, the case will only be that $v(A)=F$. And I can't continue up here, it seems unfruitful.

My **second** attempt:

Let $v$ be any truth assignment, such that the domain of $v$ contains the sentence symbols of $A$ and $\tau$.

If $v(A) = F$, given $v(A \rightarrow \tau) = T$, hence $(A \rightarrow \tau) \in \mathcal{T}_p$, this is the same problem I encountered in the first attempt.

If $v(A) = T$, given $v(A \rightarrow \tau) = T$, it has to be that $v(\tau) = T$, which is what we desired.

If you have good idea, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only finitely many sentence symbols which occur in $\tau$. Thus, since $X$ is infinite, we may pick some $A \in X$ which does not occur in $\tau$.

Consider any truth assignment $v$. Define

$$v’(B) = \begin{cases}
  \top & B = A \\
  v(B) & otherwise
\end{cases}$$

We can prove by induction on formulas that for all $\pi \in \mathcal{W}_p$, if $\pi$ does not contain $A$, then $v(\pi) = v’(\pi)$. In particular, $v(\tau) = v’(\tau)$. Since $v’(A) = \top$, we have $v’(\tau) = v’(A \to \tau)$. Since $A \to \tau$ is a tautology, $v’(A \to \tau) = \top$. So $v(\tau) = \top$.

We have shown that for all truth assignments $v$, $v(\tau) = \top$. Therefore, $\tau$ is a tautology.